# .NET 6 console app on Linux - environment name is empty

Tags: c#, .net, linux, console-application, .net-6.0

I need to load settings from `appsettings.{environment}.json` in my console app on Linux, and I use the following code:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
        {
            // IHostEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            //  ==>  env.EnvironmentName is EMPTY

            string? environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environmentName)) environmentName = string.Empty;

            configuration.AddJsonFile("./appsettings.json");
            //  ==> here it's EMPTY too !
            configuration.AddJsonFile($"./appsettings.{environmentName}.json".ToLowerInvariant());
        })
   ...
}
```

I set the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` to ***some-environment-name***, which I can check with `echo $DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`. I set this env variable in `~/.bashrc` (`export DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=somename`). And currently I run the app from bash, connecting to linux machine over SSH, so it's just `./MyApp` command.

When I run the app, I get the empty value as the environment name. Why might this happen?

## Additional info

My app is a self-contained app.

Comment: Can you please describe step by step how do you set the environment variable and how do you run the app.

Comment: Note that if you set the env variable via `export NAME=VALUE` it will set the variable only for current terminal instance, so if you run the app from another terminal instance or via IDE it will have no effect.

Comment: One thing which surprises me - if `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is not set then  `hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` should be `Production`. Unless you figure it out or somebody else answers this question - I will try to repro tomorrow but I would recommend to check the config files if it is overridden somewhere among them.

Comment: ok, I just figured it out - I run my app not with just `./MyApp`, I do it with __sudo__: `sudo ./MyApp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, my bad! I run my app not just with `./MyApp` command. I used:

```
sudo ./MyApp
```

In the case of `sudo` the environment is completely new, thus there are no variables defined for the user I'm currently using in shell. In order to pass those variables, I need to specify them in the command explicitely:

```
sudo DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=myenv ./MyApp
```

Comment: ...why are you running your process under `sudo` though? What does your program do that justifies that amount of _sheer risk_ of hosing your system?